# loading data without deleting the tree node?

Tags: godot

for now I'm using this autoload https://github.com/Ceisri/Godot-Action-Combat/blob/main/scripts/SaveState.gd,

it's from a tutorial, to save the position of entities, it deletes the entire scene and then replaces it with a new scene where all the entities maintain their stats and saved data (including position) if they are in the group "Save" , it works but it's not compatibple with a main menu scene, if I simply make a button called "save 1" and you press it, it's supposed to call the func load_game() and instance the world, problem is... it doesn't work because pressing the button deletes the scene as it is created. however if you are already inside the scene, loading and saving works perfectly fine.

[image]

```
func load_game():

var save_file = File.new()
if not save_file.file_exists(save_filename):
    return

var saved_nodes = get_tree().get_nodes_in_group("Saved")

for node in saved_nodes:
    node.queue_free()

save_file.open(save_filename,File.READ)
while save_file.get_position() < save_file.get_len():
    var node_data = parse_json(save_file.get_line())
    var new_obj = load(node_data.filename).instance()
    get_node(node_data.parent).call_deferred('add_child',new_obj)
    new_obj.load_save_stats(node_data)
```